# Crossbrowser onMouseenter

Tags: javascript, events

I'm having some issues attaching the `onMouseover` to a whole element and its children, so i decided to take a look at the Microsoft `onMouseenter` which is based on the mouse position, now i'm wondering if there is a cross browser solution, or atleast a fix for the `onMouseover` to be applied to the div children as well.

P.S. i'm not supposed to use jQuery or other frameworks for this.

Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Here's a better solution than my original. It instead tests `e.relatedTarget` against `this.parentNode`.

Seems to give accurate results:

```
if(  e.relatedTarget !== this.parentNode ) return;
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FPKKX/1/

...so you'd do:

```
el.onmouseover = function( e ) {
    // typical event obj fix

    if(  e.relatedTarget !== this.parentNode ) return;

    // This will only log to the console for the <div>
    console.log( e.target.tagName, e.relatedTarget.tagName );
};
```

---

**Original**

**This solution really is incomplete. It will require better per-element tracking since moving off of an inner element will fire the event on the outer.**

<s>You should simply be able to do a test to replicate the behavior of `mouseenter`.</s>

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FPKKX/ *(read the code comments, and open your console)*

```
el.onmouseover = function( e ) {
    // typical event obj fix

    // if the event is the result of bubbling, return.
    if( this !== e.target ) return;

    // rest of code
};
```

Now the code after the `if()` will only fire if the target of the event is the same as the element to which the handler was applied, effectively rendering event bubbling ineffective for that event.

*Note that this isn't perfect. If there are inner elements that are aligned directly against one of the inner edges of the container, the element to receive the event may be the inner one if the mouse enters at that point. Tweaking will be needed.*

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use a library such as jQuery, there is a mouseenter event which is made to be cross-browser:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: No, unfortunately jQuery shouldn't be used for my case :(

Comment: What are the circumstances regarding your case, then?

Comment: The fact that i'm building a widget and lightweight, no conflict are the most important factors.